# BigData - Hadoop (File System)

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am very new to Bigdata and Haddop technologies. While understanding the architecture I have got few below quesiton. Please help me in understanding the same.

1) Who is a Client and HDFS architecture?

2) If my file is 128 mb then ideally it should devide into 2 blocak as 64mb each. But my question is where this file chopping/splitting will happen. Is it on client side. If so, how it will happen? Because I am trying to understand when I am sending 128 mb file to hdfs, how the splitting will happen. Please help me regarding the same.

3) Who are the compitetators for BigData.

4) What are the disadvantages with the BigData.

Thanks in Advance
Shiva

Comment: This is way too broad for this site. Please edit your question to an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: just google it. You can find the answers for all the questions.

Answer (score 1):

1) 'Client' is term used to refer Project owners,after all bigdata is evaluated for business improvement of client.'Hadoop architecture' signifies the set of rules and standards which forms core where every one needs to obey.Example:After constructing four pillars in zero level one cannot construct 6 pillars in next level.

2) Default block size is 64 followed by 128,256 . One can explicitly mentioned block size in xml file. In general , Partition is used to reduce network overhead while performing read/write Operation.So, one cannot expect to send 1TB of data in single shot.Here , the architecture comes in to play ,We need not worry about complete understanding of how and why the Hadoop architecture takes care of it. As we Know abstraction in java,"We need not know complete details of how the implementation is done".

3) As of now there are no Competitors of bigdata ,Bigdata it self is used to understand the business drawbacks and improve business.Example:Amazon uses bigdata to understand user's choices and preferences,Twitter,Facebook,Linkedin,Netflix are social sites which use Bigdata.

4) As said there are no dis-advantages of Bigdata. To be more specific ,There are drawbacks of Hadoop architecture i.e Hadoop uses hard disk to read/write operations , which is high in latency.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Who is a Client and HDFS architecture?**

I don't understand what you trying to know about client of HDFS. If i understand correctly client can be anything either Some Visualization tool/Reporting tool (Ex:Tableau) or any other target like Oracle/Hana. It depends on how u want to use the HDFS data. There is no specific client.

**2) If my file is 128 mb then ideally it should devide into 2 block as 64mb each. But my question is where this file chopping/splitting will happen. Is it on client side. If so, how it will happen? Because I am trying to understand when I am sending 128 mb file to hdfs, how the splitting will happen. Please help me regarding the same.**

First you have to understand the difference between block size and Split size. Both are different ideally. 
Block is the physical representation of data. Split is the logical representation of data present in Block. As Job startup input splits will be created. Based on input splite recrd reader will be created. Record reader responsibility is by getting reference from i/p splits & creates actual KV pair. All this will be created by InputFormat. I/p Split will useful to get complete record.

When user submits request client library will take that request, client library itself will creates i/p splits & other classes and gives complete details to resource manager.

**Change replication factor**
Open the hdfs-site.xml file. This file is usually found in the conf/ folder of the Hadoop installation directory. Change or add the following property to hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property> 
<name>dfs.replication<name> 
<value>3<value> 
<description>Block Replication<description> 
<property>
```

Hadoop Distributed File System was designed to hold and manage large amounts of data; therefore typical HDFS block sizes are significantly larger than the block sizes you would see for a traditional filesystem (for example, the filesystem on my laptop uses a block size of 4 KB). The block size setting is used by HDFS to divide files into blocks and then distribute those blocks across the cluster. For example, if a cluster is using a block size of 64 MB, and a 128-MB text file was put in to HDFS, HDFS would split the file into two blocks (128 MB/64 MB) and distribute the two chunks to the data nodes in the cluster.

**Change block size.**
Open the hdfs-site.xml file. This file is usually found in the conf/ folder of the Hadoop installation directory.Set the following property in hdfs-site.xml:

```
 <property> 
    <name>dfs.block.size<name> 
    <value>134217728<value> 
    <description>Block size<description> 
    <property>
```

hdfs-site.xml is used to configure HDFS. Changing the dfs.block.size property in hdfs-site.xml will change the default block size for all the files placed into HDFS. In this case, we set the dfs.block.size to 128 MB. Changing this setting will not affect the block size of any files currently in HDFS. It will only affect the block size of files placed into HDFS after this setting has taken effect.

**3) Who are the compitetators for BigData.**
hadoop is opensource maintained by Apache opensource project foundation.
Major competitors in Enterprise hadoop are hortonworks, Clouders, MapR

**4) What are the disadvantages with the BigData.**
Not good for many small files.
Not fit for real time data processing.
Potential stability issues
Security